# What does"one-past-the-last-element" mean in vectors?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm learning vectors and am confused on how the array is copying to thevector here

```
double p[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<double> a(p, p+5);
```

I also know `std::vector<double> a(3,5);` means `make room for 3 and initialize them with 5. How does the above code work?

The second point is I read the paragraph from where I copied the above code.

> Understanding the second point is crucial when working with vectors or
>   any other standard containers. The controlled sequence is always
>   expressed in terms of [first, one-past-last)—not only for ctors, but
>   also for every function that operates on a range of elements.

I don't know what is the meant by `[first, one-past-last)` ?
I know mathematically but don't know why/how vector copy the array in this way?

**Edited**

another related question

> The member function `end()` returns an iterator that "points" to
>   `one-past-the-last-element` in the sequence. Note that dereferencing the
>   iterator returned by `end()` is illegal and has undefined results.

Can you explain this `one-past-the-last-element` what is it? and why?

Comment: std::vector has overloaded constructors thats why above code works. and `[first, one-past-last)` means first element is included and one-past-last is excluded, which is pointer to last-element+1

Comment: @AngelusMortis but why? and I also edited my question. reload.

Comment: read the answer now :) , basically one-past-last pointer is used to determine if you reached end of vector and returned as object to check and compare etc

Answer (score 16):

Never dereference `end()` or `rend()` from STL containers, as they do not point to valid elements.
This picture below can help you visualize this.

[image]

The advantage of an half open range is:
 1. Handling of empty ranges occur when begin() == end()
 2. Iterating over the elements can be intuitively done by checking until the iterator equals end().

Comment: (maybe it would clearer with 0-4 instead of 1-5 as inidices)

Comment: @UnKnown Because `i++` supposedly creates a copy of `i` first before incrementing it while `++i` does not. This really doesn't matter these days though because compilers can easily optimize this out.

Comment: `1. Handling of empty ranges occur when begin() == end()` can you explore please?

Comment: @UnKnown std::vector<int> v; assert(v.begin() == v.end());  An empty vector will have the same iterator for begin() and end().

Answer (score 5):

Strongly coupled with containers (e.g. vector, list, map) is the concept of iterators. An iterator is a C++ abstraction of a pointer. I.e. an iterator points to an object inside the container (or to one past the last element), and dereferencing the iterator means accessing that element.

Lets take for instance a vector of 4 elements:

```
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |  |
  ^           ^   ^
  |           |   |
  |           |   one past the end (outside of the container elements)
  |           last element           
  first element
```

The (algorithms in the) standard template library operate on ranges, rather than on containers. This way you can apply operations, not only to the entire container, but also to ranges (consecutive elements of the container).

A range is specified by `[first, last)` (inclusive first, exclusive last). That's why you need an iterator to one past the end: to specify a range equal to the entire contents of the container. But as that iterator points outside of it, it is illegal to dereference it.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor of `std::vector` has several overloads.

For `std::vector<double> a(3,5);` the fill constructor is used :

```
explicit vector (size_type n);
         vector (size_type n, const value_type& val,
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

This takes a `size` parameter as it's first parameter and an optional and third parameter, the second parameter specifies the value you want to give the newly created objects.

```
double p[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<double> a(p, p+5);
```

Uses another overload of the constructor, namely the range constructor:

```
template <class InputIterator>
  vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
          const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

This takes an iterator to the start of a collection and the `end()` iterator and traverses and adds to the `vector` until `first == last`.

The reason why `end()` is implemented as `one-past-the-last-element` is because this allows for implementations to check for equality like:

```
while(first != last)
{
  //savely add value of first to vector
  ++first;
}
```

Comment: +1 for while lop. Just to confirm. if last end without `one-past` then 5 could skipped in my given array?

Comment: @UnKnown If `end()` was expected to not point `one-past` then the constructor would read one past the actual array, something unwanted.

Comment: can you give me link that can clear my all questions or confusion related to this one? because I'm again confused how contructor could read one past the actual array?

Comment: @UnKnown `std::vector<double> a(p, p+6);` would read one past the actual array. Because `p` is passed as an iterator/pointer pointer arithmetic is applied to `p+6` which just points to  the memory address `sizeof(double) * 6 + p`. this memory address doesn't contain any values of `p` because `p` has only 5 elements so you're not reading `p` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Iterators are an abstraction of pointers.

A half-open interval `[a,b)` is defined as all elements `x>=a` and `x<b`.  The advantage of it is that `[a,a)` is well defined *and empty* for any `a`.

Anything that can be incremented and compared equal can define a half open interval.  So `[ptr1,ptr2)` is the element `ptr1` then `ptr1+1` then `ptr1+2` until you reach `ptr2`, but not including `ptr2`.

For iterators, it is similar -- except we do not always have random access.  So we talk about `next` instead of `+1`.

Pointers still count as a kind-of iterator.

A range of iterators or pointers "talks about" the elements pointed to.  So when a vector takes a pair of iterators (first, and one-past-the-end), this defines a half-open interval of iterators, which also defines a collection of values they point to.

You can construct the vector from such a half-open range.  It copies the elements poimtrd to into the vector.