# Why point to memory location one past the last element in an array or vector?

Tags: c++, arrays

Suppose we have an array named `data` of size `5`. If we pass this array as an argument to `std::end` function like

```
int *ptr = std::end(data);
```

It will return a pointer pointing to the memory location **one past the last element** in the array.

**Question**

What's the point of having a pointer pointing to the memory location one past the last element in the array? Why not just point to the last element in the array?

Comment: Because of uniformity. This way all iterators act the same across all sorts of different containers. And many containers don't provide random access as array and vector do. This would make `i != j` the only option and `i < j` impossible.

Comment: Because in C++ you usually express ranges with half-closed intervals, which have many convenient properties; in this notation, the range that covers a whole container is [begin, end), with end being one element after the last.

Comment: It also makes it easy to check that a range is nonempty: `while (ptr != end(data)) ...`

Comment: It also gives a valid range for an empty sequence, where `end` is the same as `begin`.

Comment: Uisng the first possible non-valid location for a given container as the "end" location greatly simplifies looping, too.  Using a container that supplies a `ForwardIterator`, for example, you can take any valid iterator for that container, and increment that iterator to loop over the container's contents until you reach the "end" iterator, because all iterators between your starting iterator and the "end" iterator are guaranteed to be valid for that container unless an action is taken that invalidates them.

Comment: This concept is also easily extended to any range in general, where using the first iterator past the end of the range as the "end" iterator guarantees that for any starting iterator `s`, all iterators between `s` and `end` (including `s`) are guaranteed to be valid for that range (unless, of course, they're explicitly invalidated).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does"one-past-the-last-element" mean in vectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34830192/what-doesone-past-the-last-element-mean-in-vectors), [What is the past-the-end iterator in STL C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15252002/608639), [Why are Standard iterator ranges [begin, end) instead of \[begin, end\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9963401/608639), [What if I increment an iterator by 2 when it points onto the last element of a vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1057724/608639), etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be able to tell an "empty" container/sequence from one with elements in it.

If a container is empty, a pointer to its first element would be one past the end, the same as the "end" location.

A `NULL` pointer could also have been used, but since iterators are necessarily pointers, the `NULL` would not apply. The default value for the iterator could also be used. In generic programming, how would the "default" be determined uniformly across all types (bear in mind pre C++98 implementations here)?

Not all sequences/containers, are contiguous in memory, any attempt to use a comparison such as `operator <` would not be suitable. The use of equality (or inequality), operators `==` and `!=` is required, so a single point (or element) is needed to indicate the last element; the "one past the end" solves that.

For uniformity, the "end" is chosen as one past the end; it solves a lot of the issues and brought power to the STL. The half closed interval has become the norm in C++.

On a side note, the ranges library and techniques shines another light on the matter, but this was not around when the foundation for the STL was laid out.

Another side note; not all sequences correlate to a container, some sequences that are required to be iterated over are only a portion of the original container or sequence, the half closed interval offers a uniform technique to access the sequence, independently of where it is in the original container/sequence.

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9963401/3747990).

Comment: It could have been like Java iterators and collections. Null means no more.

Comment: @Brandon That doesn't work if you want to, say, iterate over elements 3-13 of a 20-element container, without first putting them in a separate container.